# How to enforce foreign keys using Xerial SQLite JDBC?

Tags: sqlite, macos, foreign-keys, java-native-interface, jdbc

According to their release notes, the [Xerial SQLite JDBC](http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC) driver supports foreign keys since version 3.6.20.1. I have tried some time now to get a foreign key constraint to be enforced, but to no avail. Here is what I came up with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
       Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

       SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();
       config.enforceForeignKeys(true);
       Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::memory:", config.toProperties());

       connection.createStatement().executeUpdate(
               "CREATE TABLE artist(" +
               "artistid    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "artistname  TEXT);");
       connection.createStatement().executeUpdate(
               "CREATE TABLE track("+
                       "trackid     INTEGER," + 
                       "trackname   TEXT," + 
                       "trackartist INTEGER," +
                       "FOREIGN KEY(trackartist) REFERENCES artist(artistid)" +
                ");");
       connection.createStatement().executeUpdate(
               "INSERT INTO track VALUES(14, 'Mr. Bojangles', 3)");
}
```

The table definitions are taken directly from the sample in the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html). This is supposed to fail, but it doesn't. I also checked, and it really inserts the tuple (no ignore or something like that).

Does anyone have any experience with that, or knows how to make it work?

**Update**

I got a [testcase from Xerial](http://code.google.com/p/xerial/source/browse/src/test/java/org/sqlite/ConnectionTest.java?repo=sqlite#68) that runs for them but fails for me. So there is nothing wrong with the code, but probably the setup. I run on Mac OS and this comes with SQLite 3.6.12 (no foreign keys) installed. Is it possible that their library uses this? How can I check this? If so, how can I make it use another version?

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key enforcement is off by default. You need to use a [PRAGMA](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable) to switch it on:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

Moreover, the SQLite library must also have been built with foreign key support at all. It probably has been though.

Comment: According to the manual the `enforceForeignKeys(true)` should do that. I also tried setting the pragma manually, but nothing changed. Since the documentation by Xerial says that foreign keys are supported, I suppose they compiled it with the appropriate options.

Comment: @Space: All I can report is that when I tried it (in another language so I won't paste the log here) then the insert worked unless I'd issued that PRAGMA first.